# How to generate buttons using a for loop in ipad application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I would like to generate buttons using a for loop.

Something like this:

```
button[] button = new button[10];
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
{
button[i].text = "some text";
}
```

Could someone please suggest a way to do this?

Comment: ok... it got added accidently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i < 20; i++) {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:...];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(...);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```